# Is there any way to build wxPython 32-bit package for Python3.10 32-bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets, python-3.10

Looks like wxPython is no longer available in 32-Bit for 32-bit-Python3.x.x versions.however Is there any way i can build wxPython in 32-bit to use it along with Python3.10.6 - 32bit?

Context of request: I have python application(wxPython is integral part of application) which should open an instance of teststand 32-bit,This is apparently not possible from Python3.10.6 64bit and hence limited to use Python3.10.6 32bit.

Comment: did you contact the author of teststand? Maybe it would be easier this way?

Comment: not yet. maybe ill check with NI if no solutions are available

Comment: it will be only worse going forward. 32-bit OS becomes ancient rather quickly... Soon it will be 128-bit OS